# Find coordinates for my database's address column

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, geocoding

I have my own database that includes: `address`, `lat`, `long`, `name`.
I have all the addresses that I want without their coordinates. Is there a way to find the coordinates in order to use them as markers on my active map?

In other words I want something to batch?! geocode my addresses that are already in to my database.

Thank you very much

**Edited:**

```
def index
if params[:search].present?
  @locations = Location.near(params[:search], 20, :order => :distance)
else
  @locations = Location.all
  @locations.each do |l|
    if l.latitude.nil?
      new_location = "#{l.address}"
      s = Geocoder.search(new_location)
      l.latitude = s[0].latitude
      l.longitude = s[0].longitude
      l.save
    end
  end
end
```

This is what I have, but it updates only my first address on the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the `gmaps4rails` gem at https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails

Here's what I use in the model one of my apps:

```
 acts_as_gmappable lat: 'latitude', lng: 'longitude', 
   process_geocoding: :geocode?,
   address: :full_address, 
   msg: "Sorry, not even Google could figure out where that is"
```

Oh, and here's my `geocode?` method:

```
def geocode?
  latitude.blank? || longitude.blank?
end
```

So when the model's `latitude` and/or `longitude` are nil, gmaps4rails automatically does a lookup and fills in the entries.

Comment: Hi Donovan, this is what i use plus geocoder. My problem is that when i use a new database that has already addresses, i want to update their coordinates.

Comment: That gem already has provisions for that, but you'll have to run a manual task to rebuild the coordinates.  In my app, I simply set longitude and latitude to nil and gmaps4rails rebuilds the location.

Comment: Thank you for your help so far. I know that will work when you create a new address through your index. But how is this going to work when you have a database with 300 addresses already without the coordinates?

Comment: If it's a one-time-deal, just run a quick `rails console` command to update the records in question.  When you save them, `acts_as_gmappable` should kick in and do it's thing.  If it happens often, create a rake task.